# Magento transactional email shows and old template even after styling it

Tags: html, magento, gmail, newsletter

I made some inline styling changes on a Transactional Emails template. My changes are visible when I preview the Transactional emails template. but the problem is when I send a test email to a gmail I still get an old version of the Transactional email template. My new changes don't show up. I cleared the cache and I did Reindexing. but my My new Transactional email template doesn't show up.

Is there a step that i'm missing? or Is this problem related to Magento or the Server?

Answer (score 1):

After creating the transactional email, you still need to assign it in the configuration to be used.

For example, to change the New Order template.

1. Go to `System > Transactional Emails` and create a new email template for `New Order`
2. Once the email template is created, go to `System > Configuration > Sales Emails > Order`
3. Change `New Order Confirmation Template` to the name of your email template.  You can also do the same for `New Order Confirmation Template for Guest` if you want to use the same template for guest customers.
4. `Save Config`, refresh your caches.

Customers will now receive your email template for New Orders.